Generic type parameter issue when defining an abstract class (circular dependency)
I'm having the following issue with an abstract class having generic types which involve FormGroup:
@Directive()
export abstract class BulkAddEnterRecords<
  TFormGroup extends { [K in keyof TFormGroup]: AbstractControl<any, any> },
  TRecordFormGroup extends { [K in keyof TRecordFormGroup]: AbstractControl<any, any> },
  TRowData extends { formGroup: FormGroup<TRecordFormGroup> },
> {
  abstract formGroup: FormGroup<TFormGroup>;
  // More code to follow
}

An example of TFormGroup can be SetValuesFormGroup (see below):
  export interface SetValuesFormGroup {
    [FieldEnum.IS_FIXED_TAGS]: FormControl<boolean>;
    [FieldEnum.IS_FIXED_ORGANISATION]: FormControl<boolean>;
    [FieldEnum.IS_FIXED_LOCATION_TYPES]: FormControl<boolean>;
    [FieldEnum.IS_FIXED_COUNTRY]: FormControl<boolean>;
  }

Getting the following error upon running ng-lint-staged lint:
error  Parsing error: '?' expected
After doing some research, I realized it's caused by the circular dependency on the generic type parameters.
So, in
TFormGroup extends { [K in keyof TFormGroup]: AbstractControl<any> } we're using TFormGroup to define itself.
If I remove extends { [K in keyof TFormGroup]: AbstractControl<any> }, the error  Parsing error: '?' expected goes away (for that line), but I get an error in abstract formGroup: FormGroup<TFormGroup>;:
Type 'TFormGroup' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [K in keyof TFormGroup]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }'.
How can I solve this?
For reference, FormGroup is defined as:
export declare class FormGroup<TControl extends {
    [K in keyof TControl]: AbstractControl<any>;
} = any> extends AbstractControl<ɵTypedOrUntyped<TControl, ɵFormGroupValue<TControl>, any>, ɵTypedOrUntyped<TControl, ɵFormGroupRawValue<TControl>, any>>

so it basically does the same I'm trying to do.
